# jQuery selection in polymer webcomponent

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, web-component

Well, out of the box, jQuery does not have support for selecting nodes inside webcomponent(s). (probably because `document.querySelector()` does not work for shadow DOM (nor it should, by definition)).

Our previous codebase was somewhat dependent on jQuery and many of the devs do not want to let go of the simplicity of `$(...)` selection. So, I wrapped up this quick and dirty trick.

```
window.$$ = function (that, selector) {
    return $(that.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(selector));
}
```

Usage (inside a lifetime callback or whenever the `host` node can be accessed):

```
jqel = $$(this, '.myClass'); // this has reference to the host
```

The question is, is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created a jquery-polymer plugin that has a lot of functions that may help you dealing with polymer shadow dom

https://github.com/digital-flowers/jquery-polymer

to select any element inside a polymer element lets say

```
<my-button id='button1'></my-button>
```

first you need to get the button shadow root using

```
$("#button1").getShadowRoot()
```

or

```
$("#button1").shadow()
```

this will return the button shadow root as jquery object then you can select anything inside it for example

```
$("#button1").shadow().find("ul > li:first")
```

cheers ;)

Comment: Thanks for the update. maybe you could use the alias `.shadow()` for the method `.getShadowRoot()` in order to better reflect the jquery philosophy. (i.e. `.parent()` instead of `.getParent()`)

Comment: hi @Sayerm i guess you are right i think i will change it to shadow()

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Jquery permits passing context as parameter [JqueryContext](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context), so the proper way would be:

```
$('selector',context)
```

As an example:

```
var component1 = document.querySelector('qr-code');
// Find some img inside qr-code component
var img1 = $('img',component1)
```